# Is it possible for a proper nonempty subset of the plane to have exactly n axes of symmetry

Tags: geometry

**Is it possible for a proper nonempty subset of the plane to have exactly n axes of symmetry?**

The question is from a rider in "five hundred challenging problems", where I can only create the case that there are infinite symmetries, like all the integer points.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading the question. What about a regular polygon with $n$ sides?

Comment: It must be a subset of infinite points.

Comment: This is unclear: you can only create "infinite symmetries" but only want $n$ axes of symmetry? Huh? Also, for counting axes, are you referring only to reflection symmetries? (i.e. is an axis of symmetry a line such that reflection across that line is a symmetry of the set?)

Comment: @EthanBolker For even $n$, we would need to be a little more careful, but I agree that a similar trick should work even then.